# не открываеться поток (c#)

Tags: c#, многопоточность

есть вот такой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] test = {"test1", "test2"};
    foreach (string testob in test)
    {
        Program programObject = new Program();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart (programObject.testm(testob)));
    }
}
static void testm(string testob)
{
    Console.WriteLine(testob);
}
```

он выдает ошибку:

```
error CS0176: Доступ к члену "Program.testm(string testob)" через ссылку на экземпляр невозможен; вместо этого уточните его, указав имя типа.
```

пробовал просто указывать testm без programObject, но это тоже не решило проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => testm(testob));
t.Start();
```

Comment: @aepot, поправил. А с параметрами можешь отдельным ответом запостить.